# Remove columns which have a number in that column name that is higher than threshold

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

There is an example table with the following columns:

- "Column A [68]"
- "Column B [90]"
- "Column C [29]"
- "Column D [133]"
- "Column E [56]"

How can all columns that have a number between the brackets that is higher than 80 be removed? (in this case "Column B [90]" and "Column D [133]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Remove =  Table.RemoveColumns(Source,List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Number.From(Text.BetweenDelimiters(_,"[", "]"))>80))
in Remove
```